# ShapeRenderer. Why are circle's pixels a little bit shaking?

Tags: java, libgdx

When I run this app, it's a little bit shaking. I can't understand, why that happens? What I should to do to circle's pixels don't shake?

```
public class Main extends ApplicationAdapter {

    ShapeRenderer shapeRenderer;

    float x,y;

    @Override
    public void create() {

        shapeRenderer = new ShapeRenderer();
        x = Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2;
        y = Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2;
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        //Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        //Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled);
        shapeRenderer.setColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
        shapeRenderer.circle(x++, y, 100);
        shapeRenderer.end();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        shapeRenderer.dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Elaborate on "shaking". You're continuously incrementing `x` so you're already continuously moving the circle.

Comment: if I add this code in render:
Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
circle moves without any pixels jitter (pixels shake). But when I delete these two lines, past frames of circle are shaking (circle's pexels are shaking).

Comment: Hard to tell without screenshots or a GIF. But, if you aren't clearing the screen, and you're continuously incrementing `x`, then it could slowly draw more and more circles across `x`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your render is not being called with the same delta(time interval) between frames causing the perceived speed to judder. Normally with LibGDX the render method is called with the delta i.e. the time since the last render, however, you are using the ApplicationAdapter.
You can compensate though by just getting the delta time yourself and changing your increment from

```
shapeRenderer.circle(x++, y, 100);
```

to

```
x=x+ (Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime()* incrementConstant);
```

Adjust the float incrementConstant as you like for speed.

Read this excellent article on adjusting for irregular time steps in games.
https://gafferongames.com/post/fix_your_timestep/